# What is difference between 'year()' and 'format('YYYY')'?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the difference between those two:

```
var year = moment().format('YYYY');
var year = moment().year();
```

Is it just type of a returned value or anything else?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The `year()` function just retrieves the year component of the underlying `Date` object, so it returns a number.

Calling `format('YYYY')` will invoke moment's string formatting functions, which will parse the format string supplied, and build a new string containing the appropriate data.  Since you only are passing `YYYY`, then the result will be a string containing the year.

If all you need is the year, then use the `year()` function.  It will be faster, as there is less work to do.

Do note that while years are the same in this regard, months are not!  Calling `format('M')` will return months in the range 1-12.  Calling `month()` will return months in the range 0-11.  This is due to the same behavior of the underlying `Date` object.

Answer (score 44):

```js
var year1 = moment().format('YYYY');
var year2 = moment().year();

console.log('using format("YYYY") : ',year1);
console.log('using year(): ',year2);

// using javascript 

var year3 = new Date().getFullYear();
console.log('using javascript :',year3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```